# Is is possible to get multiple items with jquery.ajax in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use jquery.ajax to retrieve some data from the server in a asp.net mvc application.

I am looking for a way to send back (server to client) more than one item

what can i do on the asp.net mvc side to include more items in the result

```
function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
```

in suach a way that they can be used easily in javascript code?

Comment: You could pass a json result from your server to your client, but what exactly do you need to send back? What does this `item` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are serializing a list, it's JSON-representation is also a list. Consider this example:

```
public JsonResult Fetch() {
    return Json(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

This method will return the following JSON:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which is easily enumerable in JavaScript:

```
$.get("/fetch/", function(response) {
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
         alert("Item " + response[i]);
    }
});
```

The JSON serializer can of course handle complex objects.

Comment: how should I create a list from the asp.net mvc side that is readable by javascript/jquery?

Comment: See my example, that is exactly what i'm doing. Do you want me to clarify anything?